# Nlog Log IP Address from NetCore Library Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, nlog, asp.net-core-webapi, httpcontent

I have a VS 2017 solution with multiple projects, I have a separated project with the NLog methods to use it from other projects for not include NLog in all projects.

- NetCore Rest API
- NetCore Infraestructure
- NetCore Database And persistence
- NetCore Logger
- Other NetStandard Projects with helpers and ViewModel Classes

I want to Log Client IP Address and user if it's logged in. I have seen that I have to use a template in the NLog.config, but it is not working and the log IPAddress field is empty.

What's the correct way to do it?

NLog.Config

```
<extensions>    
  <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
</extensions>

<targets>
  <target name="Database" xsi:type="Database">
    <commandText>
      INSERT INTO T_LOG
        (DATE_, APP, IPADDRESS, USER_, CENTRE, LEVEL_, LOGGER,
        METHOD, MESSAGE, EXCEPTION,
        SOURCE_FILE_PATH, LINE_NUMBER)
      VALUES(
        @Date, @App, @IPAddr, @User, @Centre, @Level, @Logger,
        @Method, @Message, @Exception,
        @SourceFilePath, @LineNumber);
    </commandText>

    <parameter name="@App" layout="${AppName}" />
    <parameter name="@IPAddr" layout="${aspnet-request-ip}" />
    <parameter name="@User" layout="" />
    <parameter name="@Centre" layout="" />
    <parameter name="@Date" layout="${longdate}" />
    <parameter name="@Level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
    <parameter name="@Logger" layout="${logger:shortName=false}"/>
    <parameter name="@Method" layout="${event-context:item=callermember}"/>
    <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}" />
    <parameter name="@Exception" layout="${exception:format=ToString}"/>
    <parameter name="@SourceFilePath" layout="${event-context:item=callerpath}" />
    <parameter name="@LineNumber" layout="${event-context:item=callerline}" />

</target>
```

Logger Class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using NLog;
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Project.Log
{
    public class CustomLogger
    {
        private readonly Logger logger;
        private Type type;

        public RhesusLog(Type type)
        {
            this.type = type;
            this.logger = LogManager.GetLogger(type.FullName);
        }

        public void Debug(string msg, Exception ex = null,
            [CallerFilePath] string CallerPath = "",
            [CallerMemberName] string CallerMember = "",
            [CallerLineNumber] int CallerLine = 0, params object[] args)
        {
            this.Log(LogLevel.Debug, msg, ex, CallerPath, CallerMember, CallerLine);
        }

        public void Info(string msg, Exception ex = null,
            [CallerFilePath] string CallerPath = "",
            [CallerMemberName] string CallerMember = "",
            [CallerLineNumber] int CallerLine = 0)
        {
            this.Log(LogLevel.Info, msg, ex, CallerPath, CallerMember, CallerLine);
        }

        // Other Levels logs ....

        private void Log(LogLevel Level, string msg,
            Exception Exception = null, string CallerPath = "",
            string CallerMember = "", int CallerLine = 0, params object[] parameters)
        {
            LogEventInfo LogEvent = new LogEventInfo(Level, this.type.FullName, msg);
            LogEvent.Parameters = parameters;
            LogEvent.Exception = Exception;
            LogEvent.Properties.Add("callerpath", CallerPath);
            LogEvent.Properties.Add("callermember", CallerMember);
            LogEvent.Properties.Add("callerline", CallerLine);

            this.logger.Log(LogEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

I have used NLog Log and I can see this message on the Log

```
2018-09-06 23:31:44.6183 Debug Setting 'DatabaseParameterInfo.layout' to '${aspnet-request-ip}'
2018-09-06 23:31:44.6183 Debug Missing serviceProvider, so no HttpContext
```

Comment: are you using UseNLog? Please check also the internal log: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging

Comment: @Julian I have added the NLog Log on my question

Comment: how's your NLog setup? (e.g. program.cs) - see https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If NLog logs "Missing serviceProvider, so no HttpContext", the  serviceProvider isn't correctly registered to NLog.

The `UseNLog()` on `IWebHostBuilder` will register the `ServiceProvider` and add the `HttpContextAccessor` to the DI system.

So you should double check if you call UseNLog() on the right time, see this example of program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // NLog: setup the logger first to catch all errors
    var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
    try
    {
        logger.Debug("init main");
        BuildWebHost(args).Run(); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //NLog: catch setup errors
        logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
        NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
    }
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
        })
        .UseNLog()  // NLog: setup NLog for Dependency injection
        .Build();
```

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2

Comment: I have to do this on Startup.cs even if I have the NLog classes on separated project as I said? I can to this and continue with my Logger class on separated project?

Comment: For ASP.NET Core you need to hook NLog into the ASP.NET Core pipeline. So you need that for every ASP.NET Core project, but not for class libraries. Of course you could create helpers to prevent code duplication

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. It works for me.